# Dart pub.dev published plugin, broken images in README.md

Tags: github, dart, markdown, dart-pub

I published a plugin on pub.dev and also on GitHub, I have 2 screenshots displaying in README.md from Github link. These are fine on Github but are broken on pub.dev. I tried all approaches but still the same.

```
Screenshot# 01             |  Screenshot# 02
:-------------------------:|:-------------------------:
<img src="https://github.com/shahzadakram67/flutter_tex/blob/master/screenshots/Screenshot_1.png"/> | <img src="https://github.com/shahzadakram67/flutter_tex/blob/master/screenshots/Screenshot_2.png"/>
```

Github: https://github.com/shah-xad/flutter_tex

pub.dev: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tex

Comment: Found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62017182/adding-images-to-readme-of-plugin-in-pub-dev with a similar solution. I would really like to find a way to use relative paths to the repository instead of absolute URLs though if anyone has an idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The actual URL, to be used in pub.dev, should be:

```
 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shah-xad/flutter_tex/master/screenshots/Screenshot_1.png
 NOT:
 https://github.com/shahzadakram67/flutter_tex/blob/master/screenshots/Screenshot_1.png
```

Comment: Thanks ! that was helpful !

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to change the `/blob/` to `/raw/` in your Github url, so in this case would be something like:

```
"https://github.com/shahzadakram67/flutter_tex/blob/master/screenshots/Screenshot_1.png"
change to
"https://github.com/shahzadakram67/flutter_tex/raw/master/screenshots/Screenshot_1.png"
```