# Adding images to Readme of plugin in pub.dev

Tags: flutter-plugin, readme

I have a plugin called [UPI India](https://pub.dev/packages/upi_india) in **pub.dev** whose readme contains two images. Both images are visible in Readme of **Github** but not in the Readme of pub.dev

**Images in Pub**

[image: Images in Pub]

**Images in Github**
[image]

I am using absolute path in Readme.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://github.com/mdazharuddin1011999/UPI-Plugin-Flutter/blob/master/images/success.jpg" alt="Success Status" width="200"></td>
    <td><img src="https://github.com/mdazharuddin1011999/UPI-Plugin-Flutter/blob/master/images/show.gif" alt="How example looks" width="200"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: They look like that are visible to me

Comment: I actually solved the issue. Instead of using files stored in repository itself. I uploaded the files to github cdn server and used that link. Sorry I forgot to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved!
I used the cdn link instead of repository link.

```html
<img src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/42082172/82893565-d3643480-9f6e-11ea-96a7-493181df6214.gif" alt="How example looks" width="300" height="540">

<img src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/42082172/82893023-1245ba80-9f6e-11ea-868d-a55062d34086.jpg" alt="Success Status" width="300" height="540">
```

Hope it helps someone in future.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simpler way where you can try something like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://github.com/mdazharuddin1011999/UPI-Plugin-Flutter/raw/master/images/success.jpg" alt="Success Status" width="200"></td>
    <td><img src="https://github.com/mdazharuddin1011999/UPI-Plugin-Flutter/raw/master/images/show.gif" alt="How example looks" width="200"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Just change the `/blob/` to `/raw/` in your Github url.

Comment: Do you know why this works?